Functionality of glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance for OpenGL (ES) 3
I am currently using VAO to draw two objects, using vertices and colors.
To draw multiple of these objects I added another buffer to each VAO to supply matrices for the transformation and use glDrawElementsInstanced.
This works fine so far.
Now I read that it is better to combine all objects into one VAO.
Then I could use the glDrawElements with the appropriate parameters to draw both objects once with one VAO binding and one or two draw calls.
Also fine.
When I want to draw multiple of both objects (using OpenGL 4) I could use glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance, then I could use again the buffer for transformations to supply the matrices. This should result in one VAO binding and two draw calls with again appropriate parameters.
But how do I implement this behaviour for OpenGL 3 or OpenGL ES 3?
a) I could update the buffer for the translation matrices for the first object, bind the VAO and run the instanced draw call for the first object. Then I could update the buffer for the translation matrices for the second object, bind the vao again(?) and run the instanced draw call for the second object.
b) Or I could use TBOs. So create two buffers for the transformations and bind them to one textures each. Then I would have to update the two buffers (binded to the textures), bind one VAO (for vertices and colors), bind the first texture and run the instanced draw call for the first object.
After that simply(?) bind the second texture and run the instanced draw call for the second object.
Of course the vertex shaders must be different for both solution.
Are there any advantages/disadvantages in solution a) or b)?
Or is there a better way of doing this instead of using glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance?

Passing matrices through per-instance vertex attributes in the VAO is possible, but can be relatively heavy on some hardware. The more common way would be to pass an array of matrices in a uniform or storage buffer, and then index into that in the vertex shader with gl_InstanceID. If you do this you can manually add whatever uniform offsets you like to the instance ID.
Also note that in general, VAOs tend not to give any significant efficiency advantage over just recreating attribute bindings every draw call. They sound like a good idea, but are rarely used in my experience.

Thanks for your answer. The number of uniforms is fixed and must be set while compiling the shader right? And with "storage buffer" you mean a "shader storage buffer object"? Are SSBOs usable for OpenGL ES 3.x? I found them only for OpenGL 4.x.

"Must be fixed". No, for buffer objects, the last entry in a buffer's structure definition can be an unsized array.

"Are SSBOs usable for OpenGL ES 3.x?" SSBOs added in OpenGL ES 3.1. For 3.0 you can use UBOs (functionally the same for read-only inputs, although UBOs often have a smaller size limit).

Many thanks for your information. It seems that OpenGL supports SSBOs since Version 4.3 only. So to get nearly the same behaviour I need to use at least OpenGL ES 3.1 und OpenGL 4.3.
You mean that uniforms can be used with buffer objects of undetermined size? Do you know if this is possible in OpenGL and OpenGL ES?

Uniform buffers in OpenGL ES 3.0.
